# How to create a new column by combining two mutually exclusive columns within the same dataset, using R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data-set as an example, where I want to Create column C. Columns A and B are always mutually exclusive, except for dual NAs.

```
|Unique IQ         Column A        Column B          Column C (A+B) (The one I wish to create)
|10204050          Top10%          NA                Top10%
|10204051          NA              Top20%            Top20%
|10204052          Top90%          NA                Top90%
|10204053          Top80%          NA                Top80%
|10204054          NA              Top80%            Top80%
|10204055          NA              NA                NA
```

I tried various forms of merge, left_join, combine, but I have failed with each of them. This ought to be rather simple, albeit I could not find anything specifically helping with that.

Thank you!

Comment: With `coalesce`: `Column C = coalesce(ColA, ColB)`

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment you can use `coalesce`, a `dplyr` function:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Column_C = coalesce(Column_A, Column_B)
```